# How can I make .querySelectorAll() or .forEach() work in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, foreach

I want to remove all elements with class `sample`.

This is working well in Chrome and Safari:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.sample').forEach(function(e) {
    e.parentNode.removeChild(e);
});
```

Here is the error I get in Firefox:

> TypeError: document.querySelectorAll(...).forEach is not a function

Comment: Does `document.querySelectorAll('.sample')` return an `Array`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`document.querySelectorAll` returns a NodeList which is indexed like an array, but not an Array so you can't call the array methods on it.

You can use `Array.from(nodeList)` in ES6 or `Array.prototype.slice.call(nodeList)` for ES5

```
 Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('selector')).forEach(el => el)
```

Comment: They have implemented the `forEach` method on their `NodeList` but it's non standard, so should not be relied upon.

Comment: This worked: `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.sample')).forEach(function(e) {
 e.parentNode.removeChild(e);
});`

Comment: Unfortunately, in front end dev we can only go  as fast as the worst browsers support for features. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Can anyone tell me what's the difference between forEach(el => {}) && forEach(function(){})

Answer (score 3):

I've just tested `document.querySelectorAll('.element')` with `.forEach` in Firefox 71, and it worked.

CanIUse shows that it's been supported in FF, since version 50 (late 2016): https://caniuse.com/#search=forEach

Older versions of FF have a 0.25% marketshare, so `.forEach` should be safe to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a polyfill (see https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach):

```
if (window.NodeList && !NodeList.prototype.forEach) {
    NodeList.prototype.forEach = function (callback, thisArg) {
        thisArg = thisArg || window;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            callback.call(thisArg, this[i], i, this);
        }
    };
}
```

This adds the forEach method to the NodeList, if it is missing.