# How to view/hide div only in that id

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a div where it is assigned by an id.

My goal is to make that div have two sides: the front and the back (assigned by class) 
* the front is shown as default, while the back will only be shown upon user click

My question is, when trying to make a lot of this div, how can I achieve this kind of scenario, where it will only show/hide those classes only in that particular id?

```
<div id="user01" onclick="userId(this)">
    <div class="front">
        <img src="../media/media/alumni/sdc/01.jpg"> User name on front 
    </div>
    <div class="back">
        other info on back
    </div>
</div>
```

**user01 is assigned per each user (ex.: the first user is 01, while the second is 02, and so on...)

thanks :)

Comment: Do you want to solve the question using pure javascript or it is possible to use jQuery?

Comment: I guess he would have tagged jQuery if he wanted to use it. Also it's easy without jQuery.

Comment: jQuery is just a JavaScript library you guys...

Comment: @AluanHaddad, I wanted to clarify what it is possible to use jQuery JavaScript library. In some cases it expects pure JavaScript.

Comment: @Alexander and I wanted to clarify that even if using jQuery, it would still be pure JavaScript.

Comment: @mplungjan While it's okay to point that out, we're long past the point where we'd have to support browsers that don't understand `querySelectorAll` thankfully.

Comment: Yes, but not forEach. You may be past that, but us who work in corporate have to support older browsers. Only very recently were we allowed to scrap IE8.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41054259/how-can-i-make-queryselectorall-or-foreach-work-in-firefox - forEach is iffy on an html collection: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a css `class` on top of your `id`:

```
<div id="user01" class="user">
```

Then, in your Javascript, use `document.querySelectorAll` along with that `class`:

```
let users = document.querySelectorAll('.user')
```

Now you can iterate over this DOM node collection that is returned by document.querySelectorAll and add an event listener to each one:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(users, function(user) {
  user.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    /* your code to be executed on click 
       each user is available here as 'this' */
    // example:
    this.classList.toggle('active')
  })
})
```

As mplungjan pointed out, Edge and IE don't support `forEach` on Node collections, so `Array.prototype.forEach.call(users, function(user) ...` comes in as a replacement for `users.forEach(function(user) { ...`.

As a last step, add the CSS that flips your stuff:

```
.user .front {
  transition: opacity .3s ease;  
  opacity: 1;
}
.user.active .front {
  opacity: 0;
}
.user .back {
  transition: opacity .3s ease;  
  opacity: 0;
}
.user.active .back {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```js
let users = document.querySelectorAll('.user')

Array.prototype.forEach.call(users, function(user) {
  user.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    /* your code to be executed on click 
       each user is available here as 'this' */
    // example:
    this.classList.toggle('active')
  })
})
```

```css
.user {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative; /* this allows absolute position of children */
}

.user:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.user .front,
.user .back {
  transition: opacity .3s ease;
  color: white;
  position: absolute; /* position both "sides" on top of each other */
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.user .front img,
.user .back img {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
}

.user .front span,
.user .back span {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.3), 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: block;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 1;
}

.front {
  opacity: 1;
}

.user.active .front {
  opacity: 0;
}

.back {
  background-color: #333;
  opacity: 0;
}

.user.active .back {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="user" id="user01">
  <div class="front">
    <img src="https://lorempixel.com/output/business-q-c-200-200-8.jpg"><span>User 1 name on front</span>
  </div>
  <div class="back">
    other info on back for User 1
  </div>
</div>
<div class="user" id="user02">
  <div class="front">
    <img src="https://lorempixel.com/output/business-q-c-200-200-2.jpg"><span>User 2 name on front</span>
  </div>
  <div class="back">
    other info on back for User 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, we had conflicting edits and it seems thsose got lost on the way. Can you re-edit them into the code?

Comment: Very few browsers have support for forEach on an HTMLCollection. A simpler loop is a better bet. querySelectorAll is supported on all newer browsers