# Why is forEach not working in Edge?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, microsoft-edge

This code is not working in Edge browser. The accordion panel does not open and I get this error:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'forEach'

```
const accordionBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-accordion');

accordionBtn.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const currItem = e.currentTarget;

    currItem.classList.toggle("open");
}))
```

Comment: which error are you seeing in the console? Perhaps the element hasn't loaded by the time the `script` runs - can you do `console.log(accordionBtn)`?

Comment: The error probably means: "code to new for this browser"

Comment: I don't think so, arrow functions are supported in Edge, and there isn't anything else too funky in there

Comment: This is console says: "Object doesn't support property or method 'forEach'"

Comment: [...accordionBtn].forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const currItem = e.currentTarget;

    currItem.classList.toggle("open");
}))

This variant works!

Comment: This is very similar to [How can I make .querySelectorAll() or .forEach() work in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41054259/5764553) and I suspect it has the same underlying problem, even though that question mentions Firefox.

Comment: It would be great if you post a working fiddle so we can fork and test with browsers and live edit it in a real case example (with html and css too).

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList`, which is array-*like*, but is not an array.

Answer (score 9):

Note this should work in Edge 16+ and across the latest versions of other browsers [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach). I manually tested Edge 17 and verified it works there.

#### Workaround

The issue stems from the fact that `querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList` instead of an `Array` *in all browsers*. While `Array` has supported `forEach` for some time, only more recently has the API been added to `NodeList`.

If you want to use this and need to support older browser versions, you can create a trivial polyfill by copying the implementation from `Array` itself (works in IE9+):

```js
if (window.NodeList && !NodeList.prototype.forEach) {
    NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
}
```

#### What about `filter` and `map`?

Also worth noting is that a number of other helpful APIs like `filter` and `map` still do not exist on `NodeList` *in any browser*. Therefore if you want the full experience, your best bet is to copy the items into a *real* `Array`.

In most modern browsers this can be done using [`Array.from(nodelist)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) or via the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) `[...nodelist]`. However, if you need to support IE you can use `slice` (among other creative techniques) to get the job done:

`var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(nodelist);`

Answer (score -2):

This variant works!

```
const accordionBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-accordion');

[...accordionBtn].forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const currItem = e.currentTarget;

    currItem.classList.toggle("open");
}))
```