# Javascript error on expanding table row in Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I have this js code that expands and collapses html table rows. It works in **Firefox** and **Chrome**:

```
const id = "item-" + item.split(" ").join("");
const itemRow = document.getElementById(id);
itemRow.classList.toggle("open");

const elems = document.getElementsByClassName(item);

if (itemRow.className.split(" ").indexOf("open") > -1) {
  itemRow.classList.remove("closed");
  [...elems].forEach(e => {
    e.classList.remove("hidden-item");
  });
} else {
  itemRow.classList.add("closed");
  [...elems].forEach(e => {
    e.classList.add("hidden-item")
  });
}
```

But in **Edge** I get a "function expected" error in the browser console on line 9 (the `forEach`).

Any idea what this means and how to fix it for Edge?

Comment: FYI: `itemRow.classList.includes("open")` is a better way to write the first test.

Comment: That looks like thw workaround described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51824545/why-is-foreach-not-working-in-edge), so it should work.

Comment: Also, what's the purpose of using the spread `[...elems]`?  Why not just: `elems.forEach`?

Comment: I get the error 'elems.forEach is not a function' in the browser console.

Comment: @Blazes The spread is a workaround for versions of Edge that don't have `NodeList.protype.forEach`

Comment: What version of Edge are you using? They both should work in Edge 16 and later.

Comment: I have Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1098.0

Comment: I tried to test your sample code on my side with the **Microsoft Edge 44.19041.423.0 Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.19041**. I found that your code works fine without any error on line `[...elems].forEach(e => {`. We can see that you are using the Edge 42 version, for testing purposes can you make a test with the Edge 44 version to check the result? If the issue still persists then I suggest you provide a code example with the HTML and JS code that can help us to reproduce the issue accurately. If it is possible for you then you can also consider moving to the latest Edge Chromium browser.