# how can i have one function be used on multiple items without creating seperate ids?

Tags: javascript

I have a game where there are balloons and each balloon has an `onclick` attribute which passes the id into a JS function to change the css.

Example:

```
<div id="balloon" class="container" onclick="popBalloon(this.id);"></div>
```

clicking this item will call the function below

```
function popBalloon(id){
    document.getElementById(id).setAttribute("class","pop");
}
```

Problem is that I have multiples balloons of the same type, and instead of using a unique id for each one, I would like a way to determine the specific balloon being clicked using the same attribute names.

Is this possible?

Comment: This is exactly the kind of thing *classes* are handy for.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` returns a collection of the elements with that class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of current answers suggest a function that defines click listener to a group of elements however you asked how to omit unique IDs where there are too many elements in a game. The simple answer is to pass OBJECT instead of ID to the function:

```
<div class="container" onclick="popBalloon(this);"></div>
```

and in the function:

```
function popBalloon(myobj){
    myobj.setAttribute("class","pop");
}
```

Thats all.

Answer (score 4):

If you pass `event` as the function parameter, you can use [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) to get the clicked Element

```js
function popBalloon (event) {
    event.target.setAttribute("class", "pop");
}
```

```css
div {  
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.container {
  background-color: red;
}

.pop {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" onclick="popBalloon(event);"></div>
<div class="container" onclick="popBalloon(event);"></div>
<div class="container" onclick="popBalloon(event);"></div>
<div class="container" onclick="popBalloon(event);"></div>
<div class="container" onclick="popBalloon(event);"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do it is add some class to all the balloons. Let's modify your code a bit

```
<div  class="balloon"></div>
<div  class="balloon"></div>
<div  class="balloon"></div>
```

I have 3 of those divs with a class of balloon here. For the js we can do

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".balloon")).forEach(balloon=>{
balloon.addEventListener('click',()=>{
//On click event here
});
});
```

Here's how you add a click event to each of the balloon.

Comment: `.forEach()` works with the [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) that `querySelectorAll` returns, you don't need `Array.from()`

Comment: You might wanna refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41054259/how-can-i-make-queryselectorall-or-foreach-work-in-firefox before you downvote the answer for using Array.from(). I'm just posting a solution which works in all cases.

Comment: @Light you might wanna look over the same documentation you added with your comment as well. Here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList

Comment: Yeah, I saw my mistake after you had posted your initial comment - missed that while fetching the URL I'm afraid

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually entering the function signature in each balloon entry, handle it all in the javascript below. Throw all those balloons into a list. As Scott Hunter suggested, place each balloon in a class. Let's call it "balloon". Then add an event listener to each of those balloons. Here's a quick demo.

```js
var balloonArray = document.querySelectorAll(".balloon");

balloonArray.forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('click', function() {
    item.innerText = "Clicked";
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  color: white;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container balloon" style="background-color: blue">Click me</div>
<div class="container balloon" style="background-color: red">Click me</div>
<div class="container balloon" style="background-color: green">Click me</div>
```